# What is the difference of using special variable $_ and @_ in Perl?

Tags: perl

Please explain what exactly the difference of `$_` and `@_` is in Perl. 
When to use which, given by example code.

Comment: Is there something in perldoc perlvar you did not understand?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When in a subroutine, the array `@_` gives the arguments passed to the given subroutine.  For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub print_em
{
  foreach my $arg (@_)
  {
    print "You passed in $arg.\n";
  }
}

print_em("foo","bar","baz");
```

The output is

```
You passed in foo.
You passed in bar.
You passed in baz.
```

The scalar `$_` is usually used as a variable within a loop.  For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Note that we are not declaring a variable
# that takes on the values 1 through 5.
foreach(1..5) 
{
  print "$_\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Likewise, we could have slightly rewritten the subroutine `print_em` above as

```
sub print_em
{
  foreach(@_)
  {
    print "You passed in $_.\n";
  }
}
```

or even as the more compact

```
sub print_em{ print "You passed in $_.\n" foreach(@_);}
```

The variable `$_` can also be used as a "default argument" for certain functions.  For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$_="foobar";

if(/bar/) #We do not have to write $_=~/bar/
{
  print "matched!\n";
}
```

which, of course, outputs `matched!`.

Take a look at [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for more information on these and Perl's other "magic variables".

Comment: as a perl beginner, the part that confused me is that `$_` is described as the default input and pattern searching space and below there are functions listed that uses `$_` as default argument:

`abs, alarm, chomp, chop, chr, chroot, cos, defined, eval, exp, glob, hex, int, lc, lcfirst, length, log, lstat, mkdir, oct, ord, pos, print, quotemeta, readlink, readpipe, ref, require, reverse (in scalar context only), rmdir, sin, split (on its second argument), sqrt, stat, study, uc, ucfirst, unlink, unpack.`

Comment: You can write `chomp($var)` for example. Or just `chomp()` without an argument. If the latter is the case, chomp() will do it on $_. But just a beginner tip. Don't use "$_" at all expect map, grep or something else where you don't have another choice.

Answer (score 9):

Jack Maney's reply covers your exact question, but I also wanted to note something: you shouldn't be fooled by just the name portion of the variable. The sigal matters, as well. `$_` and `@_` are totally different variables, as are `$foo` and `@foo`, and also `$bar` and `%bar`. Perl stores them completely separate from each other.

Comment: +1: A very good point.  This is also a good reason to avoid explicit declaration of [typeglobs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles), mostly because you no longer need them.

Answer (score 3):

One commonly seen example had to do with I/O. This code...

```
while(<>)
{
  chomp;
  print if(m/^chr1/);
}
```

...is functionally equivalent to this code.

```
while(my $line = <STDIN>)
{
  chomp($line);
  print($line) if($line =~ m/^chr1/);
}
```

Any time you have a loop the `$_` variable is populated, but there is also a more explicit syntax. This code...

```
foreach(@a)
{
  print;
  chomp;
  push(@b, $_)
}
```

...is functionally equivalent to this code.

```
foreach my $value(@a)
{
  print($value);
  chomp($value);
  push(@b, $value);
}
```

One thing to keep in mind with `$_` and other magic variables is that they can be quite cryptic to a novel programmer. Over time, I have used these less and less in favor of more explicit syntax that (hopefully) makes it easier for others to understand the intent of the code.

Comment: after reading `foreach(@a)
{
  print;
  chomp;
  push(@b, $_)
}
` the first thing I thought was: "I HATE PERL" then I read further  `foreach my $value(@a)
{
  print($value);
  chomp($value);
  push(@b, $value);
}
` does the same, since then I thought: "I LOVE perl!" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Neither `$_` nor `@_` is inherently special. Aside from being global, they are completely normal variables. They are not magical. Nothing special happens when one assign to them or reads from them.

The reason `@_` is used so often is Perl places the arguments of the function. If you want to get the args passed to your sub, you'll need to access `@_`.

```
 sub f {
    my ($x, $y) = @_;
    ...
 }
```

The reason `$_` is used so often is that some Perl operators assign to it by default, and others use its value as a default for their argument. It can lead to shorter code if you embrace it, but you never *have* to use it.

```
for my $x (@x) { say $x; }
   vs
for (@x) { say; }
```

Comment: Errr, something very special indeed happens when you assign to @_ in a subroutine, eg: sub addX { $_[0] .= 'X' } my $foo='foo'; addX($foo); print $foo;  # :-)

Comment: @tadmc, I'm quite aware that sub calls uses existing scalars for the elements of `@_` instead of making new ones. This is called aliasing, and it can be done with any variables, not just the elements of `@_`. e.g. `$y=4; for $x ($y) { $x=5; } say $y;`. Having two names for one variable doesn't make the variable special. It's actually very common. (Ever import a sub?)

Comment: @ikegami => Except for the fact that in normal usage (letting perl assign to them) both `@_` and `$_` usually contain aliases, which is definitely a "special" behavior.  So yes, something special will normally happen when you assign to them.

Comment: @Eric Strom, `$_` is only aliased by `for $_`. If `$_` is special because you can do `for $_`, then so is `$x`. By your argument, every scalar is special. But we know that's false (by definition), so the argument is invalid.

Comment: @ikegami => `$x` and every other scalar can be special, but usually are not.  `$_` and `@_` usually are special by default. Saying otherwise is very misleading.  You also seem to have conveniently forgotten about `map` and `grep` which non-optionally alias to `$_`

Comment: @Eric Strom, I'll agree with "`for` iterator variables are special", but there's nothing special about `$_` unless you explicitly make it special.

Comment: @tadmc, What I jus said to Eric Strom contradicts what I said to you  earlier about `@_`, so I'll conceded that `@_` is special inside a sub, but I already said as much in my post.

Comment: @Eric Strom, I disagree with this "by default" for `$_`. It's not even close to true. In this thread, which is all about showing "how `$_` is special", `$_` is only aliased at some point in 42% of the snippets. If you look at the lines that use `$_`, `$_` is only aliased in 67% of them.

Comment: @Eric Strom, Besides, nothing you've saying contradicts my Answer, so I'm not sure what your point is. I never said they weren't special; I said they were inherently special. Then I explained how people make them special.